# How to reorder list in Python to avoid repeating elements?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, sequence

I am trying to check if a list has any consecutive repeating elements *and then* reorder it such that the repeats are avoided. If that is impossible, then return False. For example:

```
checkRepeat([1,2])
Out[61]: [1, 2]

checkRepeat([1,2,2])
Out[62]: [2, 1, 2]

checkRepeat([1,2,2,1,1])
Out[63]: [1, 2, 1, 2, 1]

checkRepeat([1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3])
Out[64]: [1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]

checkRepeat([1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3])
Out[65]: [3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2]

checkRepeat([1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3])
Out[66]: [3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3]

checkRepeat([1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3])
Out[67]: False
```

Here is what I have. Is there a more elegant solution?

```
from itertools import groupby
def checkRepeat(lst,maxIter=1000):
    """Returns a list that has no repeating elements. Will try for a max of 1000 iterations by default and return False if such a list can't be found"""

    def hasRepeat(lst):
        """Returns true if there are any repeats"""
        return len([x[0] for x in groupby(lst)]) < len(lst)


    offset=numIter=0        
    while hasRepeat(lst) and numIter<maxIter:
        for i,curElt in enumerate(lst):
            try:
                if lst[i]==lst[i+1]:
                    lst[i+1],lst[(i+offset) % len(lst)] = lst[(i+offset) % len(lst)],lst[i+1] #swap j+1 with j+offset. wrap around the list
            except:
                break
        offset+=1
        numIter+=1
    if numIter==maxIter:
        return False
    else:
        return lst
```

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like to improve, it could be a good fit for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Just brainstorming an algorithm, but I'd probably do this by building up a count of each element, then adding an instance of the non-previous element with the highest unused count. If at any point all your non-previous elements have 0 count available, return false. It should require only two traversals of the original list, one to count elements and then one to choose each element of the reordered list.

Comment: @Heslacher - From "is there a more elegant solution," I assume that the OP has some kind of working solution and would like to make it more elegant if possible.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 from the title "How to reorder list in Python to avoid repeating elements?" it would be closed as off topic.

Comment: But you are right. I didn't read the question, my bad.

Comment: @Heslacher - Maybe the OP was unaware of CR's existence and was trying to shoehorn his question into SO's format. Anyway, I would hope that people on CR would read more than just the title before closing it as off-topic.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 usually we do, just sometimes, like now, we react a little bit alergic if we read such a title and see a suggestion of posting a question to cr.

Comment: Thank you guys. I was, in fact, unaware of CodeReview. The solution above works, but is not optimal. I'll repost it in CR pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

You may try probability equation

Number which is repeating highest number of times must be always lessthen  count of other numbers.

```
[1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3,3]
 7< (3+2) false

[1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3,3]
 6< (3+2)  true

 [1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3]
 5< (3+3)  true
```

code

```
from itertools import groupby
>>> a =[1,2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,3]
>>> s = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(a)]
>>> s
[1, 2, 2, 5]
>>> max(s) < (sum(s)-max(s))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the algorithm I alluded to in comments implemented, using the very useful `collections.Counter` class:

```
from collections import Counter

def check_repeat(sequence):
    if not sequence:
        return []
    element_counts = Counter(sequence)
    new_sequence = []
    elements_chosen = 0
    elements_needed = len(sequence)
    previous_element_chosen = None
    while elements_chosen < elements_needed:
        candidates_needed = 1 if previous_element_chosen is None else 2
        candidates = element_counts.most_common(candidates_needed)
        candidate = (candidates[0] if 
            (len(candidates) < 2 or candidates[0][0] != previous_element_chosen)
            else candidates[1])
        if candidate[1] <= 0:
            return False
        else:
            new_sequence.append(candidate[0])
            element_counts[candidate[0]] -= 1
            previous_element_chosen = candidate[0]
            elements_chosen += 1
    return new_sequence
```

This needs some refinement if `None` is a valid value in your sequence, or if you care about stability to any degree. If the elements of your sequence are not hashable, it won't work at all.

And that ternary `candidate = ...` assignment is probably clearer broken up a bit more.